# why my string not work as URL?

Tags: jquery

I am generating a URL using Timestamp like this :

```
var writeDate = function(){
    var x = new Date();
    year = x.getFullYear();
    month = (x.getMonth()+1) < 10 ? '0'+(x.getMonth()+1) : (x.getMonth()+1);
    date = x.getDate() < 10 ? '0'+x.getDate() : x.getDate();
    time = x.getHours() < 10 ? '0'+x.getHours() : x.getHours();
    minute = x.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0'+x.getMinutes() : x.getMinutes();

    var timeStamp = String(year+'-'+month+'-'+date+' '+time+':'+minute+':00.000');
    return String("http://107.20.173.235/BlufinAPI/Service/WhackAScrip.svc/GetWASOneMinuteSensexDatawithPosition?TimeStamp="+timeStamp);

}
```

// calling using a function

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: writeDate(),//getting URL but not retrieving the live data
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (msg) {
               $(msg).each(function(i,value){
                    seArray[i]=value.CurrentPrice;
               })
               showResult();
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                    console.log('update:'+msg);
            }
```

then, i am calling my json function using returned url, but it's retrieving the live data is it wrong anything?

Comment: Have you tried looking at what writeDate() returns? console.info is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing **encodeURI** in your writeDate function for timestamp, like:

```
var writeDate = function(){
  ....
  .....
  var timeStamp = String(year+'-'+month+'-'+date+' '+time+':'+minute+':00.000');
  timeStamp = encodeURI(timeStamp);
  return String("http://107.20.173.235/BlufinAPI/Service/WhackAScrip.svc /GetWASOneMinuteSensexDatawithPosition?TimeStamp="+timeStamp);
}
```

Then use in ajax url.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I did a small test to see the function and it seemed normal for me

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $('#getLatest').click(function() {
        console.log("came here");
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: writeDate(),//getting URL but not retrieving the live data
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (msg) {
               $(msg).each(function(i,value){
                    seArray[i]=value.CurrentPrice;
               })
               showResult();
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                    console.log('update:'+msg);
            }
        });
    });
    var writeDate = function(){
        var x = new Date();
        year = x.getFullYear();
        month = (x.getMonth()+1) < 10 ? '0'+(x.getMonth()+1) : (x.getMonth()+1);
        date = x.getDate() < 10 ? '0'+x.getDate() : x.getDate();
        time = x.getHours() < 10 ? '0'+x.getHours() : x.getHours();
        minute = x.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0'+x.getMinutes() : x.getMinutes();
        seconds = x.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0'+x.getSeconds() : x.getSeconds();

            //This is just for debug
        alert("This is debug alert before calling timestamp " + year+'-'+month+'-'+date+' '+time+':'+minute+':'+seconds+'.000');
        var timeStamp = String(year+'-'+month+'-'+date+' '+time+':'+minute+':'+seconds+'.000');
        alert("This is debug alert after calling timestamp " + timeStamp);
        return String("http://107.20.173.235/BlufinAPI/Service/WhackAScrip.svc/GetWASOneMinuteSensexDatawithPosition?TimeStamp="+timeStamp);
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="getLatest">Get Latest Date</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I just added the seconds to make sure the date was changing but be adviced this date is the client side date as your using Javascript, if you want the server side date you better give the date depending on the server time not the client time.

Regards,
Gabriel